# CSS3/HTML5 NavBar behavior... Can it be set to "Hide itself" after a menu item is selected?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

(Newbie) This code works, but leaves the navbar in view after the user clicks... I'd like the screen to scroll to the user's choice, and the navbar get out of the way... (in all viewport widths...)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button> 
            <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="img/logo-nav.png" data-at2x="img/logo-nav@2x.png" alt="site name"></a> disabled-->
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#Features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Author">Author</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com/FOO COOKBOOK" class="button">Buy Now</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you may have to use a bit of javascript (JQuery);

just add this code before the < / head> tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
                $(".navbar-collapse").slideDown("slow")
            });
        $("ul.nav > li > a").click(function() {
  $(".navbar-collapse").slideUp("slow");
        });
});

      </script>
```

Also, I would take the button out of the "container".

Comment: No Luck... and I tried it both ways... as is, and with the button, moved up to just above the container.  What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot some closing braces. The code should work well now, try it.